# Django: Store a dictionary in a compressed binary format

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to store a dictionary in a compressed binary form in PostgreSQL. The reason is that this dictionary object might some day become too big (hundreds of millions of values).

I found this snippet: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2014/ and changed it to this:

```
class CompressedBinaryField(models.BinaryField):
    __metaclass__ = models.SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value:
            return value

        try:
            return value.decode('bz2').decode('utf-8')
        except Exception:
            return value

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if not value:
            return value
        try:
            value.decode('bz2')
            return value
        except Exception:
            try:
                tmp = value.encode('utf-8').encode('bz2')
            except Exception:
                return value
            else:
                if len(tmp) > len(value):
                    return value

                return tmp
```

I am storing the dictionary with this command:

```
_dict = {}
MyModel.objects.create(
    user=user,
    data=repr(_dict),  # data is a CompressedBinaryField.
)
```

This works.

However when I retrieve the object and try to use it with such a command:

```
item = MyModel.objects.get(user=user)
curr_dict = eval(item.data)
```

I get this error:

`TypeError('eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object',)`

I think `item.data` is a buffer-type object for some reason.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would encourage you to look into [`pickle` field for object serialization in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) where the data is converted to a bytestream and stored.

> The pickle module implements a fundamental, but powerful algorithm for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure. “Pickling” is the process whereby a Python object hierarchy is converted into a byte stream, and “unpickling” is the inverse operation, whereby a byte stream is converted back into an object hierarchy. Pickling (and unpickling) is alternatively known as “serialization”, “marshalling,” [1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) or “flattening”, however, to avoid confusion, the terms used here are “pickling” and “unpickling”.

To retrieve data, you would be "unpickling".

[More info here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-external-objects)

There is also a [django app called `django-picklefield`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-picklefield) which is widely used.

The downside of your approach is, you have to take into consideration so many aspects. Also, use of `eval` is not recommended for security, etc..